# Why didn't Lyra ask the alethiometer who Father Gomez was and what he was doing there?

Tags: his-dark-materials, the-amber-spyglass

In *The Amber Spyglass*, after Dr Malone observed the man with the rifle casing out the mulefa village and then told Lyra and Will about the man, why didn't Lyra ask the alethiometer who the man was and what he was doing there? They sort of brushed it off with some lame explanation. I would have thought it would be a significant event because there should not be any other human around.

**Updated:**

> “Listen,” Mary said reluctantly, and told Lyra about the man she’d seen the night before.
>
> As she spoke, Will came to join them, and both he and Lyra listened, wide-eyed and serious.
>
> “He’s probably just a traveler and he found a window and wandered through from somewhere else,” Lyra said when Mary had finished. “Like Will’s father did. There’s bound to be all kinds of openings now. Anyway, if he just turned around and left, he can’t have meant to do anything bad, can he?”
>
> “I don’t know. I didn’t like it. And I’m worried about you going off on your own—or I would be if I didn’t know you’d already done far more dangerous things than that. Oh, I don’t know. But please be careful. Please look all around. At least out on the prairie you can see someone coming from a long way off …”
>
> “If we do, we can escape straight away into another world, so he won’t be able to hurt us,” Will said.

Comment: Could you paste a quotation including the "lame explanation" for reference?

Comment: (no time for a proper answer) doesn't Lyra mostly use the alethiometer to *work out what to *do** rather than anything else?

Comment: also, at the time they are going out to urgently find their daemons, a pressing task if ever there was one

Answer (score 1):

Lyra sees this man as an inconvenience in what she now sees as important: the recovery of her dæmon and her relationship with Will.  If she asks the alethiometer it might say "He is extremely dangerous, exercise maximum caution" - and then she will not be allowed to go out, and she'll be denied the private time with Will that she wants. If she doesn't ask the alethiometer she can pretend that there is no risk.

So she makes a pretty lame excuse.  Teenagers' perception of risk is often pretty skewed. She doesn't want there to be a dangerous man stalking her on the plains, so she chooses not to find out for sure. There are lots of cases of teenagers who, for example, get pregnant, but choose not to take a pregnancy test, because they are worried it might come back positive*.

Mary doesn't press the point, but Mary has less experience with Lyra's use of the alethiometer than we do. She has seen it used back in Oxford, but Lyra has hardly used it at all recently.  Mary may simply have forgotten that Lyra has an alethiometer, and her own skill with the i-ching is not nearly enough to find out the detailed motives of this strange man.

Finally, of course, out-of-universe, it is necessary to get Lyra and Will out and alone together, as this leads to the denouement of the series. So Pullman has to get his characters to ignore this risk, and by doing so he builds tension etc.

---

(*) To be fair, older adults do this too.